# For intense iteration, does front-end vs back-end matter?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I've got a Sinatra app that displays a bunch of info queried from a database. Because of the format of the info returned (such as having and admin's id number, but not their name), I end up doing a lot of:

```
<% admins.each do |admin| %>
  <% users.select {|user| user.id == admin.id} %>
    <%= <li> user.name </li> %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Nested iterations take time and I was wondering if, for big lists, there's a reasonable performance difference between doing the code above or doing the heavy lifting in the controller and having a readymade list for the erb template.

Thanks a bunch!

**edit:** FWIW, the database in question is mongodb and the server is making a few database calls (from different collections) to present the information to the client.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the answer of the front-end vs back-end issue.

But this will help your case specifically:

You should be using this:

```
Admin.includes(:users)
```

This blog post, can also be helpful: http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Comment: You're making a big assumption that the ORM in question is ActiveRecord. This isn't a Rails app, it's a Sinatra app.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It's mongodb. I've edited the question to reflect that. Sweet blog post though!

Comment: Mongodb is the database - but what is the ORM? How are you querying your admin records from the database?

Comment: Querying with the [mongo ruby driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver). All the queries are done on the back end, but I can't decide whether to sort/process information on the front or back.